# Quantum measurement - How does this commutator correspond to the following?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From the book [Quantum Measurement by Vladimir B. Braginsky and Farid Ya.Khalili](https://www.google.co.uk/shopping/product/9631055216359596476?es_sm=91&q=Quantum%20Measurement%20vladimir&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&espv=210&biw=1280&bih=679&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.QSuMw9GwAyY.O&tch=1&ech=1&psi=UqWGUp_MNpKShQfW0IGwDg.1384555866632.5&ei=Y6WGUo2cB8HChAf3i4HwDA&ved=0CE8QpiswAA)

How do they go from 5.18 to 5.19?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [Qmechanic's discussion (especially point III)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41880/what-does-the-canonical-commutation-relation-ccr-tell-me-about-the-overlap-bet) from a related thread on physics.SE.

The SE robot thinks my answer is trivial and relegated it to a comment, so I'm adding more words to foil its interference. You should be able to find what you need in Qmechanic's post.